# How to save css stylesheet pointer on php session?

Tags: php, css

I want to allow user change my website theme color by clicking on a button. Currently I save the css pointer onto the url. But when jump to other page, the css pointer is disappear from the url of new page, so the theme color back to default. How to make every pages remember the current selected css? Can I save the css pointer to php session? How to do that?

Codes :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-<?php if ($css=="blue" || $css == "") echo "blue"; else echo $css; ?>.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="csstheme" /> 
    <?php require_once("session.php"); ?>       
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?<?php print $querystring;?>&css=blue" ><img src="http://plekz.com/images/layouts/blue.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?<?php print $querystring;?>&css=green" ><img src="http://plekz.com/images/layouts/green.jpg" /></a> 
        <a href="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?<?php print $querystring;?>&css=pink" ><img src="http://plekz.com/images/layouts/pink.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?<?php print $querystring;?>&css=white" ><img src="http://plekz.com/images/layouts/white.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?<?php print $querystring;?>&css=red" ><img src="http://plekz.com/images/layouts/red.jpg" /></a>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the session would be a nice place to put it:

You could create a file that is called to set the theme-session. Pass the chosen theme to that file through the QueryString for instance. Then return the user back to the page they came from.

This is untested, but something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET["theme"]))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["theme"] = $_GET["theme"];
}

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

*You could throw in a switch- or if-statement as well, to make sure that the theme session only can be set to a couple of predefined values.*

Then you read the session on every page. If the theme variable is set, you use that theme, otherwise you fall back to the default theme.

Some more info for you:

- [The PHP manual on sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)